# I have a question about how the clustered-index works in Innodb

Tags: mysql, innodb, clustered-index

When we construct index, and the index information is stored in disk. But if we execute a query like select, how the index will be used. Will the index file be loaded to RAM or is there any cache will be used? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Innodb indexes are stored in the innodb_buffer_pool along with all the other data pages of innodb.

To check index usage of a query look at the `EXPLAIN {query}` output.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to waver between "clustered" and not.  I'll try to explain the distinction and the usage of each.

An InnoDB's `PRIMARY KEY` is "clustered with" the data.  There is a single BTree (actually a B+Tree) that holds all the data, sorted by the PK.

Secondary indexes are separate BTrees.  They are sorted by the column(s) specified for the index.  The leaves of such a BTree contain the PK so it can, via a second lookup, get to the entire record.

The BTrees are composed of 16KB blocks.  Each block holds several rows (Rule of Thumb: 100 rows.  In reality, between 1 and ~1000.)

Blocks are loaded into the "buffer pool" *as needed*.  An entire BTree is not preloaded.  `SELECTs` access data and index info *only* from the buffer_pool, *not* from disk.  Write operations may read from an index to locate the block where the inserted/modified/deleted row is or needs to go.  Then it request that the block be fetched from disk (unless already cached in the buffer_pool).  A background task will take care of flushing to disk.

Being a "cache", the entire data or index may *or may not* be entirely in the buffer_pool.

See Wikipedia for discussion of BTree and B+Tree.